# Improve Review Queues Help / Instructions

Tags: feature-request, review-queues, help-center

I recently got to 500 reputation on StackOverflow which grants access to the First Post and Late Answer review queues. After looking over them / their documentation for the first time, I came away sort of confused, so I just wanted to suggest that perhaps the documentation be made more clear.

For example, here are the directions on the First Post Queue:

> No Action Needed when this post needs no action from you.
>
> I'm Done is only available if you've done one of the following:
>
> - Vote up or down to rate the question's quality and usefulness
> - Edit to improve the question's appearance or clarity
> - Comment to leave constructive feedback for the author, or vote up existing comments
> - Flag to notify the moderators of serious problems
>
> Be sure to leave a comment if you can help the user out, upvote the
>   question if you can't find any problems with it, or click Skip if you
>   are not sure and want to go to the next item.

It's not terribly unclear, but take the case of a decent, but perhaps a bit trivial question. Is it supposed to be upvoted, because it's not that bad? The instructions kind of imply that. Is 'No Action Needed' the appropriate choice? Is 'Skip' better?

When does a post 'need no action' from me? The [help page](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues) says: "If you feel that the post is fine as it is, but you don't want to vote on it, click the "No Action Needed" button." But the other directions say to upvote the post if it's fine.

So in short, just think these sets of directions could be made more clear and more in agreement with each other.

Comment: I'm not really in favor of making the instructions more explicit; voting and reviews are always going to be a judgement call. Some people ration their votes for only the best posts; others upvote anything that looks like it had a little bit of effort put in and/or might benefit someone else. Other people only upvote stuff they find personally interesting. All of that stuff is usually valid, so guidance on when to vote and when to say "no action needed" should remain vague enough to allow for personal judgement.

Comment: Maybe just emphasizing that the only purpose of the queues is to get first time posts more attention would help then? Basically, make it more clear that it is just a judgement call.

Now the help page does say that: "The purpose of this queue is to give special attention to users who may need to be educated on some aspect of our model and to posts that are more likely to need improvement."

But I had (wrongly) thought that the queue had some more decisive role it played in affecting these first posts. Anyway, no big deal either way, just figured since it confused me might confuse others.

Comment: I came here looking for similar answers. Personally I am more confused what to do about low-quality posts. Do you 1. Leave a comment with links to the Help Centre (essentially "go easy on first timers"), or 2. Flag it appropriately (and let people with higher cred deal with it), or 3. All of the above? Further, some of the posts that I see in the wild from first time posters, that must have obviously made it past the queues, are also very low quality. Considering they have already had someone look at it in the queues, how do you handle it then?

Comment: Agreed that it is confusing. I think examples would be a good form of additional help with regards to the queue

Comment: Personally (again), this discussion https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262055/was-i-and-stack-overflow-being-too-strict-and-unreasonable-in-closing-this-que resolved a lot of my confusion. Bottom line: SO is not the place for low quality (beginner) questions, and they should be voted to close down.