# Was I (and Stack Overflow) being too strict and unreasonable in closing this question?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, closed-questions, question-quality

This question was asked and, somewhat predictably, closed:

- [How do web designers do complicated CSS coding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24469238/how-do-web-designers-do-complicated-css-coding).

The question (reproduced at the bottom in case of deletion), to my mind, was horrible (though most of that was due to the terrible spelling, but that's salvageable, and had I considered the question sufficiently worth asking, I would have corrected the spelling and grammar happily enough) and was <del>closed</del> put on hold as 'too broad.'

In the comments, though, I had a discussion with another user (it's public information, and visible by following the link, but I'll not name that user since it serves no purpose to do so):

> **other-user-1**: These broad questions can often end up being very usefull for beginners that are new to web development.
>
> **other-user-2**: Exactly - how are people supposed to learn about modern web design if they have no idea what to even Google or how things work? The only place to start is with a broad question. Instead of making StackOverflow a welcoming place for a new user, they got 5 down votes and their question locked.
>
> **me**: "how are people supposed to learn about *<subject>*" - *elsewhere*, via any means they like. This isn't a beginners, or basics, site: it's a site for 'professional and enthusiasts.
>
> **other-user-2**: you have seen the front page right? People get help for all kinds of basic questions. Looking at your history, half of the questions you asked when you were starting out could be classified as beginners questions. If you had gotten all of those closed and down voted instead of answered - would you have stuck around?
>
> **me**: there's that, certainly; and I was lucky enough to get here when the criteria was different, and those answering were perhaps more tolerant. But this question remains, I think, too open-ended (rather than simply 'basic' or 'beginner') to be objectively answered.
>
> **other-user-2**: but it was objectively answered. There are tool chains that modern front end developers use and this was the answer that was provided and it was helpful to the person that asked. This is a prime example why so many people have stopped answering questions - we try and help and then get told that the question wasn't good enough to deserve an answer. It's just gotten ridiculous and your first comment is everything that is wrong with the StackOverflow mod squad, you don't even know what this site is for anymore.

I haven't flagged the comments of that other user because I don't feel they're offensive or problematic (though the 'StackOverflow mod squad' part sort of skirts that a little closely, but I'm perhaps being too sensitive; and obviously they're 'noisy' and, now, probably 'obsolete').

He certainly raises a valid point, though, in that my early questions were genuinely basic and, had they been downvoted to oblivion and closed by others, I probably wouldn't have stuck around.

My question, I suppose, is: is this user right? Are we becoming *too* stringent, *too* abrasive, *too* intolerant? Or, less of the '*we*': am *I* being too harsh? Is there any way this question could have been salvaged?

Influences on my current behaviour would include:

- [Are high-reputation users answering fewer questions?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252756/are-high-reputation-users-answering-fewer-questions)
- [More effective closing / downvoting of junk questions to help with the signal-noise ratio?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252561/more-effective-closing-downvoting-of-junk-questions-to-help-with-the-signal-no)
- [Question quality is dropping on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/252506/question-quality-is-dropping-on-stack-overflow)

---

Reproduced question, for posterity:

> #### How do web designers do complicated CSS coding?
>
> I am new to web designing.I am in a habbit of viewing the source code of web pages by clicking right click>view page source and what i see is CSS files flooded with vast and complicated CSS code.I have learnt CSS and CSS 3. But i often think that How could designers code such vast CSS files? How much time it takes? Do they do all the coding by typing themselves or generate the code with the help of some program. Plz do reply me.

Comment: Haven't this discussion happened a dozen times over? About hostility, being friendlier to noobs, etc.?

Comment: It's possibly happened before, but this time there seems to be a valid point: my behaviour now is, potentially, hypocritical to the reception I would have hoped for when I first became a member. And, honestly, while it might be irritating if the answers don't change, it feels that reflection on our conduct is something that should be ongoing. Though, if you feel it's a discussion that's *not* worth having voting to close would be appropriate.

Comment: Subjective: I won´t say if the current rules are good or bad, but I´m getting the impression that (for some people) rules are the main reason why this site exists. So yes, somehow he´s right... (and somehow I´m becoming that way too, don´t know why. Just thinking if a close reason applies first before thinking about answers. That´s not positive.)

Comment: Whether you consider it hypocritical or not, I think the downvotes on the question would agree that this type of question is not welcome on SO. Plus I really don't even see how that's a "beginner's question" when there really isn't even a definitive question being asked.

Comment: The answer seems the same and is what you already know -- things that worked for SO in 2008 and 2009 do not work for SO in 2014. Without going into repetitive conversation, I feel like if there's a demand for a different type of response, maybe that energy should go to a different type of website.

Comment: In response to other-user-two's last comment: it didn't get _objectively_ answered. It got answered with a bunch of tool recommendations, which we don't do because they'll be obsolete in eight months, and then the new ones will be obsolete a month and a half after _that_. Even if the question were edited to be less broad, the "toolchain recommendation" is the only direction it's likely to be able to go.

Comment: @Josh: yeah, that was my first thought on reading that comment (and only just stopped myself from continuing the debate, but decided I didn't want the inevitable argument).

Comment: A good move, @DavidThomas.

Comment: Not sure I'd be critical of the misspellings and grammar.  The OP seems like they're learning English as a second language to me..

Comment: I think this question could have been answered with a useful answer.  Sadly this is not true of any of the answers given.

Comment: @Hogan what do you mean by an "useful" answer? The question is way too open-ended. David, don't be taken by commenters' opinions -- read the question again and ask yourself "Does this fit in the current Stack Overflow scope?" The answer is clearly no.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - A short essay could be written describing the design and development process.  How programmers create complexity with simplicity.  Modular design, step wise development, code-test-iterate, etc. Tie it all up with some practical examples of how this can be  applied to front-end development and CSS in particular. Probably better if the question was on the programmers site.

Comment: @Hogan seems like that would be the epitome of the Too Broad close reason, letting alone that gets outdated fast -- task runners, preprocessors and methodologies like BEM, SMACSS, atomic design are born and forked on a daily basis.

Comment: @FabrícioMatté - You are talking about tools and details, I'm talking about approach and big picture.

Comment: @Hogan Well, I can't really picture an useful answer without diving into a decent detail level, but guess discussing it isn't of much use when our views are on the two opposite sides of the coin. `;)`

Comment: Yes, of course you were being unreasonable in this specific case. I think this was a good question, and questions like this would cut down on the spamming of low quality questions. How much it would actually help is actually debatable though, since there are always people who refuse to search and can't seem to comprehend basic instructions.

Comment: Your question is a great summary of how the site has become unfriendly to new programmers.  The answers illustrate perfectly why this is the case:  people here don't seem to want the site to be friendly to new programmers any more.

Comment: David Thomas, you maybe could have added a small comment advicing the questioner about some guides/books/.. how to efficiently code big projects in CSS, in case you know some.

Comment: @WarrenDew I completely agree but maybe this is not the worst thing. We could try to start a new programmers SE on area 51 at any time. The only thing SO has to do is to be upfront about it as much as possible in order to fight false expectations. "Come only here if you have a specific question, otherwise go away." maybe could be written in big letters on the front page. ;)

Comment: @Trilarion We could call it **SemicolonExpected.SE** or **CompileError.SE**...

Comment: @dav_i Great suggestions. May I add **IndexOutOfBounds.SE**, **NullPointerException.SE** or **AttributeError.SE** but **SemicolonExpected.SE** already sounds perfect.

Comment: @Trilarion we so need an AttributeError.SE. I'd also add UnboundLocalError.SE and KeyError.SE. And of course, InvalidSyntax.SE...

Comment: @WarrenDew: Friendliness is entirely orthogonal to the issue at hand. You seem to be suggesting that we should be "friendly" and that being "friendly" means we should accept any question regardless of how well or poorly it fits the site's formatting. That is, of course, nonsensical!

Comment: SO Summer of Love from the past is good reading on the general topic: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2012/07/kicking-off-the-summer-of-love/

Comment: Being friendly in general is just always a good idea. Everything else just shortens life.

Comment: +1 for being willing to self-analyse on (a) have long-term users benefited from being around when the rules were less strict, and (b) how can we be kind to non-vampish and earnest beginners who simply don't know where to start. I try to think on these things too. All that said, the Q still belongs on hold - it's either too broad or too subjective. Chat might be a better place to direct them to.

Comment: I feel this site like any other forum has attracted a lot of trolls. They go around looking for any reason to criticize an answer or down vote and flag a valid question. This site should be for newbies as well as we all had to start somewhere but I have seen many post and even had my answers chastised for trying to assist people in need who were not clear enough or did not know how to ask the right question. I know we have a guideline of what questions should be asked and how answers should be formatted but we all need a break once in a while. To be clear this isn't directed at your question.

Comment: Why cant we have a feature to move(by members) the question to the precise area.

Comment: You are being too sensitive and too many questions are closed.

Comment: With the original spelling i would have downvoted this question as well. When i started with web programming i'd just do "abc tutorial" and get most of the knowledge i'd need, unless it's some browser specific rendering BS. As question i'd actually accept something along the lines of "What are common tools in LAMP/Windows web development" because you'll get 90% of the very broad spectrum tools as well as that little bit of niche products you may otherwise not hear of. I'm eager to close questions which seemingly point out the OP didnt spend 5 minutes worth googling, but i'll let them know

Comment: Unfortunately there can't be an SO only for beginners. I checked Area 51 and wanted to start a proposal for **SemicolonExpected.SE** but all similar proposals are blocked by the Direcotr of Community Development at SE. See [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/72777/stack-overflow-coding-for-beginners) and [here](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/72403/coding-for-noobs). So since the noobs anyway have not chance to go somewhere else I will be even softer to them here. Bye, bye **SemicolonExpected.SE**

Answer (score 99, accepted):

There are plenty of places on the internet where people can go to ask programming questions without being held to a standard.  SO is one of the few places that's *not* like that.  It was built like that from the start, very intentionally.  It's the prime reason for so much of its success, that it has narrowed the scope of what types of questions it allows to just those to which are likely to generate quality content.

Some people don't like that.  That's fine.  SO isn't the entire internet.

Removing the site's standards and allowing these types of questions which have been shown over the site's history to generate low quality content might encourage some people to come/stay that wouldn't otherwise be members here.  Of course, it would also drive away a huge portion of the expert answerers that have generated the site's success.  Do you think that that's worth it?

Comment: I agree wholeheartedly, and under the terms you describe no, I don't think "it's worth it." But this is the first time my behaviour's been thrown into such stark relief as hypocrisy. I recognise that things change, and have to, but...the challenge made me wonder. I think trying to follow a middle-path (between the extremes of strict closure of specific types of questions and permitting anything and everything) is a road that would please no-one, but I'm cautious that we, or *I*, might be tending towards outright elitist hostility.

Comment: @DavidThomas Low quality questions need to be not answered, and the people that post them should be made aware of the fact that the questions are not currently acceptable, and have some idea of why (so they can fix the problem).  You can do that without being hostile, and generally the site is actually pretty good about discouraging hostile behavior.  Of course, some people assume that any action other than answering their question is hostile, regardless of the manner with which you go about not answering their question.  You seem to have run into such a user.

Comment: Under those terms, I'll continue with the standard of quality, then. :)

Comment: "Low quality questions need to be not answered" This needs to go in a banner somewhere for everyone to see.

Comment: I might replace *generated* with *contributed to* in the last line. We're not all experts but a great many of us contribute to the success of the site.

Comment: "Low quality questions need to be not answered" - who deems a question to be of low quality though?  To a hardened coder with years of experience I am sure many questions seem `low quality`.  To those of us that are still earning our stripes, the question(s) don't seem of lesser quality.

Comment: @Homer_J It's not about how advanced a question is, it's about how the question is being asked. Questions with a small snippet of code that can be run and shows a specific problem, along with an explanation of the problem, are higher-quality than "I want to do X. Give me the code."

Comment: @EricFinn - sure and I completely understand that.  Have to say, from experience, most do explain and ask for further information if needed.  Personally, this site and the people on it are incredibly helpful and tolerant (in terms of peoples knowledge or lack thereof).

Comment: @Homer_J [Question quality and question difficulty are orthogonal concepts](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261723/1159478).  Whether or not a question is of low quality has nothing to do with how hard it is for a programmer to solve, or how much programming experience the reader has.  It has everything to do with how clear the question is, the magnitude of its scope, whether its on topic, and so on.  New programmers are just as capable of asking quality questions as anyone, just as experienced programmers may fail to ask quality questions.

Comment: One disagreement from me: Beginner topics can generate good content, and more importantly it can stop nubile developers from posting the same questions over and over again. Of course, you'll always have those who never search before asking, and even worse basing their code on 10 year old tutorials.

Comment: "Low quality questions need to be not answered" - For all the talk about what made the site popular, this is the genesis of what will make the site unpopular. The answer to David Thomas' dilemma i simple: you either care about the rules/the site or you care about *people*. Are you here to enforce rules or build a website? or are you here because you want to help people? Do you emphasize with them; do you feel their confusion&frustration; do you want to make their day better? Any time you find yourself thinking about something other than helping people first, you're becoming part of the problem

Comment: @alcalde The reason this site has become as successful as it has is a combination of people and rules. Get rid of the rules and the right kind of people (the ones who know something) will leave. After that you can 'help' gimme-da-codez type askers to your heart's content, but the site will be dead for all practical purposes and intents.

Comment: [Optimizing for pearls...](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/06/optimizing-for-pearls-not-sand/): "We feel that the world is awash in questions, but not answers. Answers are the real unit of work in any Q&A system. Therefore, the only logical thing to do is to maximize the happiness and enjoyment of answerers. If this means aggressively downvoting or closing unworthy and uninteresting questions, so be it. Without a community of people willing to _answer_ questions, it really doesn’t matter if there are questions at all, does it?"

Comment: "It was built like that from the start, very intentionally." Seems not true to me. Judging by all the highly popular very broad and extremely upvoted but nowadays absolutely closable questions from 2009-2012 I would say SO started much more relaxed than it is nowadays. With the rest I agree.

Comment: @Trilarion you could argue that from 2009 - 2012 those broad questions to which you're referring probably were not being duplicated 10 times a week either, therefore the content was relevant.

Comment: The thing is, if people view the site as being made up of jerks, it becomes a good thing for them to do what they can to frustrate your goals. For example, I was chased away from this site the first time I came here, and I was very tempted to find any answer they had given and downvote it, not because they were bad answers, but because jerks do not deserve to have high reputations. I'm sure you have systems to prevent this, but why would you intentionally engender hostility like that? If StackOverflow gets a reputation as being full of jerks, why would people come here to ask questions?

Comment: @trlkly: they'll come here to ask questions *if the kind of questions they ask is the kind that gets answered*. If the kind of questions they ask its he kind that get closed here, then in point of fact the ideal is that they stop asking them here. I don't think SO should cultivate a reputation of being full of jerks, but it's inevitable on the internet that if you tell someone you don't want their contribution, they'll think you're a jerk. SO does not accept arbitrarily off-topic or off-style questions just to avoid that.

Comment: @r3wt [You're incorrectly equating low quality questions with beginner questions](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/261723/1159478).  Beginner questions are fine *if they are high quality questions*.  Low quality questions are not acceptable *regardless of how technically easy or hard they are to solve*.

Comment: @alcalde So the only people that matter are the people that come here, spent no time or effort researching their problem, don't bother to take the time to craft a well written question, have no consideration for the rules, and have no respect for the community or the other people in it?  The people that take considerable time out of their lives to enrich the programming community with quality content aren't people?  They don't matter?  Sorry, but no.  It's *impossible* to please everyone.  Sites have a target audience.  SO makes an effort to care about the latter group, not the former.

Comment: @Trilarion The problem there is that you're not seeing/noticing all of the closed/deleted/downvoted questions asked at around the same time.  There is a tiny fraction of a percent of questions falling into the category you're describing that came about despite the best efforts of the community to encourage quality.  They still happen even now every once in a while.  The fact that there's a very rare low quality question that ends up being upvoted doesn't mean that the community wasn't built from the ground up to generate quality content.  It simply means that the community isn't perfect.

Comment: @trlkly As per [my earlier comment](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262055/was-i-and-stack-overflow-being-too-strict-and-unreasonable-in-closing-this-que/262056?noredirect=1#comment50435_262056) you seem to think any action other than answering a low quality question is hostile.  If that's true, there's really not much that can be done for you.  Not answering your question, and instead helping you understand why it's not acceptable, in a polite manor, is not hostile.  In fact, it's entirely reasonable.

Comment: @trlkly But to answer your last question of why people will come to SO, they'll come here because *here is where they can come to get a quality answer to their question*. If they go to other sites odds are their question will be welcomed regardless of how awful it is.  It's unlikely to get an answer, and even less likely to get a quality answer, but they won't tell you your question has problems.  Given a choice between a site that forces you to improve your question to their standard to get an answer, and a site that isn't capable of answering it at all, which do you think people will choose?

Comment: @Servy I wasn't here at that time so I don't have real experience but there are quite high number of very popular questions from that time that would be closed instantly today. My guess is that indeed the rules were to some extent less strict (enforced) at these days.

Comment: @Servy I never said not answering is being a jerk. What is is saying things like "there's really not much that can be done for you." That is something people who are trying to be nice to people don't say. You are dismissing concerns rather than nicely dealing with them. The OP did the same thing, and that's what provoked the hostile reaction. Rather than address concerns, he told people to go elsewhere. Rather than explain why the question wasn't useful, he stayed very terse and unhelpful. Only after they provoked him did he start being nice.

Comment: @Trilarion Yes, the rules weren't as strict back then, I'm not refuting that.  What I'm saying is that the goal of the site, even then, SO was built to be a place where there is a standard of quality.  The line of where that standard of quality falls has changed over time, but *we've still had one* from the very start.  That is the point.  And it's important to keep scale in mind.  Even a few hundred questions along the lines you described, when compared to hundreds of thousands of questions, is still a very small percentage.

Comment: @trlkly The other user asked how he could do [thing] where [thing] is not something in the site's scope, namely how to learn about a topic from scratch.  He was told, quite correctly, that that is not what SO if for, and that [thing] is something that should be done using other means.  When you have specific questions while in the process of learning [thing] it could be entirely appropriate to come to SO and ask *that specific question*.  Politely telling someone that what they want is outside of the site's scope is being helpful, not hostile.  SO can't do everything for everyone.

Comment: @Servy - you are wholly correct in your reply to my comment earlier and I do agree.  However, I'm not referring to question difficulty in the sense of how easy a problem is it to solve.  I guess what I am trying to convey is the sense that if you 'don't know the answer', positioning the question in the first place can sometimes be difficult.  Moreover, you may position a question in a such a way that it is obvious to others that there is a different solution or option but then the question is down voted/ closed as a result.  A degree of tolerance (from everyone) is needed.

Comment: @Homer_J People can and do help question authors fix their question.  Many users spend lots of time editing questions to improve them, people very often are asking clarifying questions which help the author understand what their question is lacking, or how they might want to phrase it instead.  *The question absolutely should be closed while such discussion is happening*.  The whole point of closing a question is to prevent answers *until the question can be improved*.  People can and often do make an effort to help people understand how to improve their question.

Comment: @Servy What he said at first was not polite. It was flippant. Politeness in this context means taking something with sharp edges and and cushioning it. Both his first response and the statement of yours that I quoted above are quite raw and uncushioned, the opposite of being polite. The fact that said information can be given in a polite way does not mean the exact word choice was polite. A polite response does what it can to turn away wrath. His response provoked hostility. Compare his first response to everything he's said in this thread. It has a completely different tone.

Comment: @trlkly Specifically, how was what he said impolite? I think you may be mistaking bluntness for being impolite.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger. What people usually call "bluntness" is a form of being impolite. It's called "blunt" because it stings a bit, and being polite is about doing your best not to offend. Technically what you said is blunt, as well, since it is direct and to the point, but people don't call it such because it's not impolite. As I say in my answer down the page, the comment had a flippant tone that clearly provoked the other users. After he offended, he adopted a more conciliatory tone, which is something he should have had from the beginning.

Comment: @trlkly Those users seemed to be up in a tizzy about the question being closed as too broad before David ever said anything. I think pretty much anything he would have said to disagree with them would have provoked them.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger, now to answer your question directly. What was "impolite" was the implication is that people that want X should leave. It ridiculed their concerns as not being worthy of discussion. That's the implication, and why directness was not appropriate. And to your response after mine: if so, then the best response was not to respond at all. But I personally think a comment that focused more on the issues they were bringing up would have worked.

Comment: @trlkly The problem with that is that their concerns have been discussed extensively, right here on meta. Some may say they've been beaten to death and every time it seems that this is how the community wants it to be.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger And that's the reason for my Answer. Rather than leave commenters who get frustrated answering the same questions over and over again, answer it once and for all in a big meta question, and the link it from now on.

Comment: @trlkly "Rather than leave commenters who get frustrated answering the same questions over and over again" are you referring to answering the same question on SO over and over again or the same question on meta?

Comment: @LeonNewswanger I'm referring to the commenters, who asked the question "how are people supposed to learn about modern web design if they have no idea what to even Google or how things work." This is the question that David Thomas answered in what I describe as a "flippant tone." It's the same as the word "concerns" that you mentioned earlier.

Comment: @trlkly I guess we're just going to have to agree to disagree because I don't see his response as flippant at all. It's not like he said "They can RTFM"

Comment: @trlkly It sounds like you're simply assuming malice when there is none.  You're mis-interpreting the tone, intention, and actual statement of the comments.  When someone is asking for something that is entirely beyond the site's scope, the appropraite thing to do is tell them that what they're asking for is outside of the site's scope.   In just the same way that if he had asked for advice on balancing his checkbook the response would be, "that's not something that this site does, you'll need to find another site to ask that type of question."  It's the same thing here.

Comment: @trlkly You're incorrectly interpreting the statement that *a particular question* isn't appropriate for the site as meaning that *the user* isn't allowed to be here.  The user is welcome to come to the site and ask questions, so long as the questions meet the site's standards.  This one doesn't, and in such a way that at its very core it's not in line with the site's scope, it's not like small change here or there will fix it.  What the author wants to get out of a response is simply not what SO is offering.  He can either want something entirely different, or ask his question elsewhere.

Comment: The question and answer are in regards to *closing* the question; I think the related issue of *downvoting* is critical.  The question itself is not a bad one; it's just not a good fit for StackOverflow, so **closing** the question is valid.  However, **downvoting** the question is not necessary.  Doing so discourages the user who asked the question (unnecessarily), and I think worse, "preemptively" discourages others who see those downvotes and become concerned that they, too, might be hounded if their question isn't appropriate for SO, even if it's a good question. I think that's tragic.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum You seem to think that downvotes are like lashings, and that the world will end if you get downvotes on a post of yours.  They're an indication of the quality of the post, which, in this case, is low.  It's not an appropriate question, and the votes correctly provide that feedback not only to the post author, but to other users and the site itself.  If people are worried about asking questions that aren't appropriate for the site then *that's a good thing*.  We *want* them to take the time to make sure their questions are appropriate instead of just throwing whatever onto SO.

Comment: I don't agree.  The fact that the question is closed provides sufficient feedback, in my opinion.  You can make the argument that downvotes are not like lashings; and without doubt the world won't end because of downvotes.  But you disregard the - for lack of a better word - *human* aspect, and for that reason I disagree.  I think the criteria for downvoting has room for subjectivity, even if it's possible to point to reasons why downvotes are valid for a question like this, as you have.

Comment: unfortunately, if the user doesn't understand what a downvote means, there's nothing we can do to help them understand that. The question should be downvoted so that it doesn't show up at the top of question feeds since it is low quality. If the OP finds that to be harsh or mean, we can't really do anything about that other than comment.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum So you want to actively encourage people to continue posting inappropriate questions?

Comment: No.  But, I think that the appropriate action to take is to *close* the question.  This provides the proper feedback, and is distinct from *downvoting* questions.  I'd use a separate set of criteria for downvoting, one that I think is too complex for me to attempt to lay out here (even if I could), and which I think does contain a fair bit of subjectivity.  Of relevance, I do think that many have a tendency to downvote a question *because* they think the question should be closed.

Comment: @Servy Whether the tone was intentional or not, it is there. Italics carries with it an emphatic tone when read allowed. Doing it to the first word of a sentence, one followed by a comma, makes it even stronger. Overly emphasizing something carries a tone of irritation. I did not say there was any malice involved, and clarified in my Answer below that I think it is just frustration from having answered that concern many times. But I think frustration is the wrong response to someone who has posted in an angry, exasperated tone. A frustrated tone just isn't polite.

Comment: @Servy I am also not misinterpreting the meaning of what was said. I am telling you how it can be interpreted. I know from further context that no malice was intended at all. Plus I follow a rule of "Always assume the most favorable interpretation of what someone says online." I would not have gotten angry, but I think it's clear that the commenter did. And that's why I think we should get together and write something one time that explains it in the most polite manner possible. It's not that hard to post in a way that your tone is unlikely to be misinterpreted. It just takes more words.

Comment: @trlkly So an entirely appropriate comment was posted, with an entirely sensible message, someone completely misinterpreted an helpful and polite statement that SO is not the correct place for their question as being inappropriate, when it wasn't?  If that's what you're saying, then we agree.  If you're saying that there was anything actually inappropriate about that comment, then it would seem that you're wearing your belt around your neck.  As I've said, some people are going to assume that any answer they don't like is rude and offensive.  This wasn't.  it was a fine and polite comment.

Comment: I'm also finished with all this. It's taken over pretty much much my entire day at this point. I continue to think the first comment could have been more polite. I continue to believe what I said in my Answer below. I don't really see much point in defending that point much further. Just take it as given that I probably don't agree with whatever part of what I said that Servy will now disagree with. :p

Comment: @trlkly If i stopped myself from saying everything that someone somewhere MIGHT find offensive, simply because they're reading WAY too much into it, I wouldn't comment on anything ever.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger Indeed. It's hard enough to formulate a high quality factual answer.  Having to also think about the answer from the point of view of a hostile reading is expecting a lot.  By and large, SO is helpful, polite, and generally inviting.  But this is not a PR site for a corporation, it's an answer site for technical questions.

Comment: @KirkRoybal and others - I think that's a good point, but I also think it needs to be modulated with another perspective often missing on this site.  StackOverflow has become a powerful institution on the web, and like any powerful institution, its culture can act as a filter between the haves and the have-nots (in this case, those with technical knowledge).  It's easy, and common, for those on the "have" side to use technocratic arguments to justify the "overly high expectations" that you speak of to avoid facing this human issue.  But, I think it's important to meet those expectations.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum There are *thousands* of programming q/a sites that you can use that have virtually no standards for questions, or at least very very low standards.  SO is one of the very, very few places that someone can go to answer questions where they can actually expect question authors to create quality questions.  If you don't want to have that, there are plenty of places out there for you to go to.  If you *do* want to have quality content on a site there really isn't anywhere besides SO to go.  You can see how your proposal to basically remove SO's standards is not well received here.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum I'm all for helping beginners. If their willing to make the effort to post a good question I'm willing to make the effort to post a good answer. I really don't understand everyone these days saying that expectation is "overly high".

Comment: @Survy I said I was finished, but I had to read Servy's reply. No, I'm not saying that it was appropriate. Did it break any rules? No. But it was not the best thing to say at that particular time. The person was clearly angry, and responding in frustration doesn't work well with anger. It also was not polite, as you keep claiming, as politeness requires more than just not being rude. It requires a specific attempt not to ruffle any feathers. If you don't want to be polite, fine, but don't go making things worse by being impolite to angry people.

Comment: @trlkly Now wait... what you're saying is that I can't respond to a person who is visibly upset, judging by their comments, because if I repspond, *I'm* the one who's out of line because I didn't bend over backwards to make absolutely sure I wasn't going to offend them?

Comment: Servy - I think I'm in agreement with you regarding the importance of StackOverflow's standards.  I think the question should have been closed, as well, which, I think, is the appropriate response to this particular question and suffices to maintain the proper standards.

Comment: @trlkly It *wasn't* impolite.  There was nothing impolite about it.  Your claim that its impolite seems to indicate that you're overly sensitive and virtually nothing would ever please your sensibility.  The comment was very helpful, providing someone with information about the problem that they had raised.  Nothing about it was wrong at all.  As Leon has noted, you can't avoid offending everyone, regardless of what you do (even if you do nothing).  Some reasonable level of appropriateness needs to be set, and that comment is in no way unreasonable.

Comment: @DanNissenbaum Then it seems I misunderstood your comment.  Could you rephrase your point?

Comment: Servy - Could you please look back at my comments regarding the distinction between *closing* and *downvoting* a question.  I *think* I stated my opinion clearly in those comments, so I'd rather not take the time to rephrase.  Thanks!

Comment: @Survy And comments like this: "You can see how your proposal to basically remove SO's standards is not well received here." are why I have not been polite to you. He never once said to remove SO's standards. He made a very limited proposal to not downvote questions because you want them closed. You are lying about what people have said. Dan Nissenbaum is having to be a freaking saint to respond to you. He is an example of someone who is being intentionally polite. The reason you are having trouble understanding what is impolite about what the OP said is that you are a rude person.

Comment: @trlkly You understand that now you're doing the exact thing you just explicitly said not to do?

Comment: @DanNissenbaum I'd like to point out as a point, that sometimes getting a question with low quality closed can take hours, if it happens at all. I have active flags from over a week ago sitting open. Downvoting provides a way of letting other users know this question is low quality, because they can't see that I've already flagged it.

Comment: @trlkly It's not a lie.  It's a misinterpretation, one that I freely admitted to when he clarified his point.  Continuing to bring it us isn't productive.  Your assertion that I simply don't understand what polite is, and that you do, doesn't seem to be borne out by the responses of all of the other readers here.  They also seem to have felt that the comment in question was entirely appropriate, and that you are being entirely unreasonable in your assertion that it was rude.  After all, politeness is the result of an entire communities feelings, not any one individual.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger I just assumed that the irony was intentional to prove his point.  It's probably giving him too much credit, but it's the more entertaining interpretation.

Comment: @Survy Saying someone is "overly sensitive" is an excuse made up by people who like not being nice to people. It's like "grow a thicker skin." I have made it very clear what it would take to be satisfied. All it would take is a bit of a buffer. "I'm sorry. Stack Exchange really isn't a beginner site. If you do not have a basic understanding, there are other sites that can explain. Simply search on Google for CSS basics." That's a polite response. It acknowledges that the other person is upset. That's the first part of being polite when dealing with someone who is upset.

Comment: @trlkly Saying someone is overly sensitive can sometimes indicate the context you described, yes.  And sometimes it can mean that the person is *actually* overly sensitive, rather than everyone else being overly apathetic.  Clearly the community (and not just me) disagrees with your interpretation, and feels that you're *actually* being overly sensitive here.  This is a technical community that has its own set of values.  The fact that *you* think that an "I'm sorry" is *necessary* for that comment to be appropriate doesn't mean that it is.

Comment: Didn't David also state that the user in question was actually *not* the OP but rather a 10k plus user who should have already been well aware of the rules anyway? This whole thing seems to stem on being "polite" to beginners, but there weren't any actual beginners involved in the case at hand. Unless I missed something.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger You did indeed miss something.  It's [an 8.5k user](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1029936/bill) that apparently doesn't understand how to use SO, not a 10k+ user.

Comment: @trlkly "I thus interpret that he intended it to be offensive." Yeah, that's kind of the point we're trying to make to you here. You seem to be the only one one who's outright offended here. You and Bill.

Comment: @Servy Oh, well that changes *everything* =p

Comment: @trlkly How is it that you misinterpreted, "Then it seems I misunderstood your comment." as repeating my original point and not admitting that I misunderstood his comment?  That doesn't exactly leave a lot of room for interpretation.  He then *impolitely* responded to my request for him to rephrase the comment that I still have no idea what he's saying in by telling me to go re-read a comment posted a while earlier on an entirely different point, instead of re-phrasing the comment that I still don't understand.  As to asking if I intentionally offended you, could you link to that comment?

Comment: Downvoting a question on SO isn't like giving negative feedback on other sites.  It doesn't damage your reputation (unless you do it to extinction). Nobody sees the negative vote on your profile except you. Take it as a teachable moment and move on.

Comment: @Servy Because I read a different comment instead. Okay, so you didn't do that. But I find it incredible that you didn't understand his point. What he asked you to do was go back and read the same point again, because he laid it out extremely simply. I quote "The question itself is not a bad one; it's just not a good fit for StackOverflow, so **closing the question is valid**. However, **downvoting the question is not necessary**." And you even responded specifically to his claim about downvotes, indicating you understood him. Then all the sudden you claimed he said something else.

Comment: @trlkly Don't take offense to this (but judging by this entire conversation you probably will), you seem to take everything that's being said *personally* and you've practically turned that into a vendetta against Servy. At this point, my interpretation of what you're saying just seems like you've run out of your own valid points and now instead of debating the issue, you're trying to debate Servy's character.

Comment: @trlkly It's not just Servy or myself not agreeing with you, its the **community** as represented by votes. If you feel that the community is taking the wrong stance on this issue and that you definitively know better, you're perfectly welcome to start your own Q&A site and prove us wrong.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger I ran out of points long ago, but I've had to constantly keep repeating them over and over and over, because Survy kept not understanding me. My point was simply that I think the comment was impolite, and that the OP should try to be better in the future. I pointed out that we should do what we can to not let people think we are jerks. It's a very simple point. Survy clearly disagrees with me about it being impolite, but every post he makes has a bit of a prod in it that requires a response. He always picks at something that isn't relevant and makes me defend it.

Comment: @trlkly No one is forcing you to respond to him any more than you're forcing me to respond to you. If you truly think that he's out of line, being immature, impolite, or anything of the sort, you could have easily walked away from this conversation a long time ago. Servy is responding the way he is because you're outright ignoring the fact that the community thinks David's response was perfectly acceptable.

Comment: @LeonNewsWangler Re: the community disagreeing with me: How in the world does that make any sense? The answer to this question never brings up the point I've made. It doesn't address the comment the guy made at all. All your counterpoints tend to be voted up by 1 point. And my answer below, got one downvote and two upvotes. Sure, that doesn't mean the community supports my point, but it doesn't mean they don't, either. Since it's almost certainly one of you guys voting up the comments you agree with, there are a total of three or four people who disagree with me.

Comment: @trlkly You have made it adamantly clear that you think David's response in the situation was "impolite". Servy's answer addresses the fact that on SO, this doesn't hold true. Said answer now has 67 points. What part of that doesn't make sense to you?

Comment: @LeonNewswanger He can't force me to respond, but he can misrepresent my point multiple times so that, in the interest of being understood, I have to clarify. He kept interpreting what I said in conveniently provocative ways. He pushed exactly the right buttons that made me feel that I needed to respond. And I did try to walk away. But he had to have misinterpreted me right before I did that. So I foolishly jumped back in, despite knowing I was getting too angry. And then I started saying things I wish I hadn't. You'll notice I deleted one, but then I found out you guys apparently still see it

Comment: @LeonNewswanger No. His ANSWER has gotten 67 points. An answer that does not in any way address whether or not David's COMMENTS were impolite. It simply says he was right to close the answer, something I've never challenged. **I've never once said that his answer was wrong.** I've been always replying to things people said in the commments. My answer that *does* address David's comments has 1 vote (which I happen to know is actually at least two upvotes as it was it was downvoted once.)

Comment: @LeonNewswanger If Survy has thought this entire time that I was challenging his Answer, no wonder he's been so provocative. We would have been talking past each other this entire time, and he probably thought I said a lot of things I didn't. It seems to be the same mistake he made on another Answer where he seems to think I agreed with the answer, even though I never said such. Again, **I agree Survy's Answer is correct**. It's just incomplete, because I think David could have worded his comment better. Or, better yet, we could try my Answer down below and link a meta post.

Comment: @trlkly This will be my last response. I think we both need to concede to the point that this discussion has gotten widely off topic for the context of the original question. If you have anything else you'd like to say in regards to the actual issue at hand I'd gladly discuss it with you in a civilized fashion in chat.

Comment: And this time I'm really out. I won't even check to see if there are other responses this time. I hate having shown my angry side to this community. My only hope is that few people read meta.

Comment: No, it wasn't like this from the start, it actually helped people learn, go google most "starter" things and you will find all these questions on SO and now they are closed because of the self righteous people who took over the site.

Comment: @Servy "namely how to learn about a topic from scratch"... except that's not what the question was.

Comment: @OneOfOne I'm guessing the only reason I actually use stackoverflow is because of those same self-righteous people. The main reason I don't use other sites is the low quality of questions/answers.

Comment: Answering valid questions for a newbie doesn't mean it's a low quality answer.

Comment: @OneOfOne Of course not.  Nobody has said otherwise.  Answering invalid questions for people regardless of whether they're new or not *does* mean that the answers are almost always of low quality though.

Comment: @OneOfOne To your earlier point, you'll find that tons of those same questions were closed back when they were asked.  Only a handful weren't.  You just don't see the other questions because they're deleted, or don't attract the same level of attention.  It also ignores all of the problems that those types of questions have caused the site that it has had to deal with over the years.  That said, a question being on a "starter" topic doesn't necessarily make it a bad question.  It does make it rather likely that it's not well research, which, if true, means there's no *need* for SO to host it.

Answer (score 17):

> Exactly - how are people supposed to learn about modern web design if they have no idea what to even Google or how things work? The only place to start is with a broad question. Instead of making StackOverflow a welcoming place for a new user, they got 5 down votes and their question locked.

This presupposition that Stack Overflow *must* be that place where newbies can go, at the expense of any other concern, is prevalent and nonsensical.

Other websites do exist, with different goals and different paradigms. That question did not belong on this one.

Closing the question was absolutely the right thing to do!

Comment: disagree completely.

Comment: @r3wt: How's that? You think this website should serve the purpose of any possible newcomer to the industry, no matter what? How could that position be defensible even by the simplest tenets of logic?

Comment: No i don't think it should be for every new comer, only those willing to dedicate themselves. My argument is for the allowance of reputable members( 10k +) to write "tutorial" questions to curtail the most basic of questions which get asked here.I absolutely think questions similar, but not identical could be acceptable in specific cases. You may have went to college, and i respect that. I didn't even graduate highschool i was expelled, and i taught myself every single thing i know, with small things being picked up here and there. It would have been so much easier if i had some reliable(cont)

Comment: @r3wt: Why don't you think that this can be achieved elsewhere? This is a Q&A. Why should it also be something else? The things you talk about can be achieved with a separate system, without ruining this one. Are you in fact suggesting that beginner programmers are only capable of visiting Stack Overflow, and not other websites? They're not going to get very far at all if that is so.

Comment: (cont) tutorials on a great site like stackoverflow to teach me the ropes of web development. Instead, i learned about 500+ bad habits in php and other caveats and gotchas in multiple languages because the code in the wild out there sucks or is out of date. look at the pathetic quality of php and javascript questions we see as a result of every self learner following the same 10 year old tutorials

Comment: well yes, they need to familiarize theirselves with the manual obviously. Problem is who's going to tell them that? a site like this or some random blog with malicious code continuing the problem of ill equipped people in the workforce. People are learnin to copy and paste code together and many never bother with anything other than that.

Comment: @r3wt: It seems like you've missed my point entirely, I'm afraid.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit: Some people, like myself, are never going to be in "the industry". They may use programming only tangentially or even just for fun and are not served by elitism (who is?). To this day, StackOverflow **also** caters to these *enthusiast programmers*.

Comment: @sigma: I never claimed otherwise. I wish you people would stop bandying around the word "elitism" willy-nilly. At least learn what it means. I've stated several times now that expertise level has absolutely nothing to do with this problem, so I simply can't fathom why you keep bringing it up.

Comment: @r3wt: There are very reputable sites that do end-to-end tutorials on many programming topics (especially in web dev). There are bloggers you can subscribe to that debate whether you should solve contentious issue X by doing A, B, or C. There's excellent books on nearly any programming topic you can think of, many of them freely available in digital form (see Why's guide to Ruby). I simply don't understand this selfish stance of "if StackOverflow was a tutorial site, I would have picked up programming much more easily: therefore StackOverflow should be a tutorial site".

Answer (score 13):

I think the policy is well discussed on meta, but you seem concerned about the hypocrisy in particular.

The reason for kicking the ladder away, is that when SO first started it was primarily trying to gather a community around an idea. It tolerated some things not to the point of its idea, such as over-broad questions and outright tomfoolery.

Now SO is trying to maintain a community around its idea (and advance the idea itself, of course). It is not desperate for new users, neither is it short of experts who hang around (and answer questions) just because they like it.

So, while there have been various attempts to prevent people being *unpleasant* to new users, downvoting and closing questions that fail the current standards isn't considered a kind of unpleasantness worth avoiding. Some people think even the existing attempts go too far.

I think the expected outcome is that if you're not a programmer (yet), then you *will* be driven off Stack Overflow. However, it's now so strongly embedded in Google results that you're not going to go away and forget about it. It is hoped that you'll return once you are a programmer and your questions are suitable for the site.

People have questioned whether this is strategically sound (all over meta), or whether sticking to mission will backfire by driving away both new *and* existing users. But the source of the inconsistency is a change of tactics in response to changed circumstances. I don't think it's reasonable to accuse you of hypocrisy just because you started hanging out here at a time when SO was, in effect, on a recruitment drive. You got a special offer that's no longer available, it doesn't follow that you must advocate for the same special offer to be continued forever. The special offer was, you're allowed to ask questions now considered bad, in the hope that you'll provide good answers and ask other questions that are good.

If you feel that your old questions are weak, and would be closed and deleted if asked today, you could consider deleting them. This would be in line with SO's current policy on what questions are desirable, and would (rightly or wrongly) have the side-effect of leaving your site history in a state where you won't be criticised for contributing rubbish ;-) I've never deleted a question of my own though, I'm not sure of the practical details. If it would take mod intervention to achieve then it might not be worth the effort.

Comment: I wish SO would just be kind of a marketplace for questions and answers with perfect match-making. Then there would never be any reason for any unpleasantness against whomorever. One would just ignore what one doesn't want to see. Of course there isn't perfect filtering and I guess this is the reason why all these debates occur.

Comment: @Trilarion: right, and if we had that then we wouldn't need different SE sites for different subjects.

Comment: I don't understand why they haven't already been closed. I've seen many questions closed as having historical significance but not a fit for the site as it is. The only reason I assume they are still there is that they were eventually edited into good questions. If they are bad questions, vote to close 'em.

Comment: @SteveJessop Yes, that is the heart of Stackexchange: Q&A and nothing else. Not rules about who can do what or gets which badge or is closed or whatever. This is just to make it all work somehow. That's why all this trying to base the decisions and directions on first principles will never work completely. It's always a bit arbitrary what SO is and what it isn't.

Comment: @trlkly: I had a very brief look at the questioner's oldest questions. They seem basic, of the form "how do I do this extremely commonplace thing that's obvious to anyone who knows the language?". They don't have the same problem as the newbie question under discussion here, which was of the form "wow, I'm impressed by programming, how does anyone manage that?". Actually I think this questioner's early questions are acceptable (if not priceless), since "too easy, rtfm" isn't a close reason, but some might have argued for "lacks basic understanding" when that still existed.

Comment: Practical details are: you can't delete a question yourself if it got (upvoted?) answers and you can't delete an answer yourself if it was the accepted one. So it does indeed involve mod intervention - don't bug the mods for such things. Unless your post is extremely poor, then you could flag it for closing.

Comment: So, when is one considered to be "a programmer"? Surely this cannot be circularly defined as "whenever your questions are suitable for the site"? *Stack Overflow is a question and answer site for professional* ***and*** *enthusiast programmers*, aiming to provide *detailed answers to every question about programming* as it currently reads.

Comment: @sigma: yeah, "every question about programming" is a simplification. Other material elsewhere restricts that, for example https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask doesn't say "you can ask anything provided it's about programming". And I agree that "a programmer" is not circularly defined. I think it's a meaningful English word, albeit somewhat subjective with a fuzzy edge. I think "for programmers" could be clarified: questions should seek solutions to problems with programming that you face in your capacity as a programmer. Simply being a programmer is necessary but not sufficient.

Comment: ... so the closest I come to a straight answer to your question "when is one considered to be a programmer?" is to say, "when one is programming" ;-) Personally I'm happy for questioners to be very new to programming, just as long as they're far enough along to ask a specific question about what they're doing. The question under debate, "how to write a lot of CSS" would work better as, "I need to write a lot of CSS, are there better ways to manage it than just to type a lot?", but still faces the "takes a book to answer" barrier, which applies to new and old programmers equally.

Comment: By contrast, consider for example that on the aviation SO there are a reasonable number of questions *about aviation*, but that are asked by curious non-aviators who don't face a problem within aviation. "Ask an airline pilot". Physics has a lot of "Ask a physicist" questions, mostly answered by John Rennie, their Skeet-equivalent. I don't know if this will continue forever, but SO is explicitly not for that purpose (might be OK on programmers, I don't hang out there). The question came across to me as curiosity, not a request needed to solve a problem faced by the questioner.

Comment: @SteveJessop: I suspected they wouldn't actually be bad questions. Thanks for confirming. I didn't realize I could check myself.

Answer (score 6):

**TL;DR version**:
Rather than give flippant responses, let's create a meta question that deals with this common complaint about broad beginner questions and link to it when people complain. We don't need to constantly be redoubling effort, yet we also don't want to leave complaints completely unanswered. Either can lead to a sub-community of dissatisfied users, which can break even the best sites.

**Longer version**:
I don't think the top answer is sufficient, because I don't think things should be the same as they are. David Thomas did make a mistake, I think. Not so much in closing the question, which I agree is the best we can do under the current system, but in how he first responded to the complaints. The response was not exactly hostile, but it wasn't friendly either. The best way I can describe it is "flippant." And I know it's hard to be friendly when someone else is being provocative and when space is at a premium (see some of my comments in this very thread), but I think it's crucial to the well being of the site.

Complaints about how beginners can learn about broad subjects well enough to actually ask a "good question" are something that need to be addressed. The way that would fit well on this site, I think, is to have a meta question that addresses this oft-heard complaint. It can be well crafted to be as inoffensive as possible, and possibly include links that will give people another place to go to ask such broad questions, leaving them feeling helped rather than turned away.

Then, rather than risk offending people by trying to shoehorn a good response in the short amount of space as a comment, you can just redirect people there, with maybe something like "We hear your complaints, and we've addressed that topic **here**. If you think the question hasn't been adequately answered, feel free to leave a comment there. Comments on questions aren't really for complaints about the site as a whole."

I've seen so many sites fail at dealing with legitimate complaints. They wind up getting frustrated, evolving from helpful, to annoyed, to flippant, and, finally, to hostile. At some point they anger a large enough group of people that, eventually, the wrong person gets angry, one who chooses to fight back. One site I know of was hacked twice and had its source of revenue cut off twice and wound up with it community severely fractured into two spinoff sites because of it.

I realize you can't make absolutely everyone happy, but that's not an excuse not to try and improve relations with the disgruntled. I'm starting to see the basic warning signs of a fractured community here (as all these complainers clearly have been around long enough to have comment privileges, and I've even seem some with pretty high reps), and that needs to be nipped in the bud. To not do so because you can't please everyone is just allowing the perfect to be the enemy of the good.

Answer (score 5):

**Part 1:** The "too broad" close reason says it all:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be
>   too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set
>   or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

Too many answers, too long answers. You would have to write a whole tutorial. Most people here do not want to do that.

The concentration on detailed, narrowed questions which can be answered in a reasonable format implies that you **must have a certain level of knowledge about the subject before**. That's just a consequence of us not wanting to write tutorials.

In the beginning of SO (2009-2012) this was different and the broad questions from this time are still (partly) helpful. Just have a look at the high number of views and upvotes and you see that there is a market for this.

There are plenty of other places on the internet where people can get basic information. The only reasonable thing we can do is **occasionally giving some advice how to find them** when closing a question. I do it sometimes in a comment - nothing bad about a friendly word if you have the time for it.

But the only other alternative would be for us to start writing tutorials and I don't think we want that nor that we are necessarily good at that.

**Part 2:** How could this question have been salvaged (by the questioner)?

It's actually not that difficult:

> How to efficiently code feature XXX in CSS?

Simply ask for a specific thing and (and define what you mean by efficient) and you should get good answers. Even the simple fact that asking a non too broad question is not that difficult should be seen as a sure sign that the original question can stay closed.

Answer (score 0):

A good tag description, [like the java one](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/java/info) should include the answer to this kind of basic how-do-I-get-started question, or links to tutorials that would give the information, and educate the questioner.

I absolutely agree with those who would like to see this question answered on SO - but the appropriate place already exists, and it is the tag description, not a question.

Actually, I think the tag descriptions are a much underrated feature of SO - where else on the internet can you go, and get summaries of such a wide range of technical topics, with links to tutorials?  I have learned a lot by reading SO tag descriptions, and following their links.

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think people actually read those.

Comment: Upvoting because the reasoning is good, even if you disagree with it. It's not a "bad answer" that deserves to be downvoted into oblivion.

Comment: @trlkly Speaking of questions that get answered repeatedly on meta, voting on meta is different than voting on SO. Here a downvote doesn't imply poor quality, it just means the person disagrees with you.

Comment: @LeonNewswanger It also doesn't hurt your rep in any way, something I figured out having written an answer myself. Still, I don't like that it goes gray when it gets low enough, as it makes it hard to read. There are replies to me on RoyHB's comment that are nearly impossible to read. So I have an interest in keeping questions above whatever threshold makes them go gray.

Comment: @cimmanon - yes, I agree.  But that is only because nothing on SO question help points you to tag descriptions as a help source.    Nobody has really explained why they disagree with this comment - do people not like the tag descriptions? would they like to see the very helpful content of the java one deleted?

Answer (score 0):

It isn't a good question as it is actually stated, and I don't see the way to change it without dramatically changing it, which means writing it from scratch.

There are 2 separate issues, which are interesting and deserve interesting questions:

1. How to setup the environment in which many separate CSS files will be merged into single one, and in the same time being able to do development. The answer would be, naturally, using `@import` directive, but also configuring the CSS integrator/compressor into build process.
2. It's in danger to be opinion-based, depending how it is written, but it's about working with multiple CSS files and organizing them into modules. Some frameworks provide some modularization patterns and some standards about it, but not always they are very strict.

As for that question, I'd close it with suggestions to the OP, how could that question be formed to provide potentially valuable answers.

Answer (score -1):

The "too broad" close reason reads:

> There are either too many possible answers, or good answers would be too long for this format. Please add details to narrow the answer set or to isolate an issue that can be answered in a few paragraphs.

So in what way does this question fall under that? Are there too many possible answers, or would good answers be too long?

If there are too many good answers, along what lines would some of them be? Bill's and nicholaschris's answers seem to just about cover everything that could be usefully said to answer this question.

If good answers would be too long, then for what reason are Bill and nicholaschris's answers not "good"?

Very often when people talk about StackOverflow being "strict", it really seems like the exact opposite. Mentally expanding close reasons to cover more than they actually should is the opposite of strictness, it's a form of laxity in applying the rules.

Answer (score -2):

I haven't (and won't) look at your early questions so you have to decide for yourself if you would have closed them today. If so, delete them or fix them.

I do the same every once in a while. Recently I worked through my regex answers to improve the ones that could be improved and deleted some that could not.

So, when other people claim that you did ask bad questions in the past and you think they are right, then the right thing to do is not allow more bad questions, but improve your part of the problem by fixing what you did wrong but did survive anyway.

It was correct closing that question and if I had a question like this in my history, I'd delete it instantly.

Answer (score -10):

If the following hasn't already been suggested by others I'd be surprised, but...

In my opinion, the thing to do is to set up another Stack Exchange forum that is specifically dedicated to these kinds of too-general, often newbish questions.  And maybe even a way to close a topic on SO and automatically create a link to a new topic on Stack Whatever.

- There are undoubtedly people who enjoy helping others with these kinds of issues who would support the new forum.
- One of the best ways to learn is to teach others - the people who asked a question on the Stack Whatever forum (or who's question had been closed here and referred to there) might tend hang around and to help others as their own knowledge grew.
- The worst thing that could happen to Stack Exchange would be for it to grow a reputation as a place where people risk low-level humiliation or embarrassment if their question doesn't fit or if their English language skills are 'developing' rather than 'fluent'.
- Closing topics is perfectly legitimate when people fail to do any meaningful research, or exhibit simple laziness or really poor preparation.  But I tend to agree that closing topics just because a person isn't sure quite what to ask can be quite harsh.

There may be such a Stack Exchange forum already but if so I don't know about it.

Thanks to David for raising the issue and being concerned about it.

Comment: Mo, the solution is not to create another SE site that tolerates poor quality questions. There are dozens (if not hundreds) of other sites on the internet that do that already. SE has been specifically designed and implemented to *not* be one of those other sites.

Comment: Two things. 1st, **Stack Overflow *is not* a forum, it's a *Q&A* site.** 2nd, people *have* suggested [creating a new Stack Overflow for beginners](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/split-stack-overflow)... ***multiple*** times...and each request has been **rejected** by the community.

Comment: @KenWhite This is part of the problem. Stop thinking about the questions/the site. Think about *people*. This is like doctors and health insurance companies who become obsessed with policies or paperwork or billing or symptoms. These are real live people with confusion, concern and frustration. You shouldn't be here to create a certain type of website; you should be here to help people. You should want to be putting smiles on people's faces, not building a gated community where undesirables are kicked out.

Comment: ok, enough with the downvotes.  I wasn't aware of the history and I didn't know that the word forum is taboo.  I now understand the views expressed.  This was my first ever post to meta.  I now understand how someone who is a Stack Overflow newb feels when they post a less than adequate question or answer that is deemed 'inappropriate'.

Comment: @RoyHB Just a note: downvotes on Meta are very different from downvotes on the SO main site. Downvoting on Meta simply means "I don't agree with you", whereas on SO main, it means something else entirely :-)

Comment: @alcalde: Stop thinking about the people. You can not achieve world peace by creating SE sites.  We have a site, a goal, and we work to achieve that. Other people having other goals can go and achieve that too, just elsewhere.

Comment: \o/ yay for http://crapexchange.com

Comment: You should never take downvotes personally, they are not an attack on your intelligence or character.

Comment: @alcalde That does not work. Letting people not knowing basic math into a university to learn advanced physics, or letting anyone work as a doctor is not a good idea. This is not elitism. This site has a goal. It aims to be a quality Q&A site. People crying all the time don't understand this simple statement. There are other sites where you can ask any kind of question. If SO is not the place for you, why not go there, instead of trying to change SO?

Comment: @alcalde: SO (and the rest of SE) are not about **people**. They're about knowledge. This is not a personal "let's teach everyone to program" or "let's all be friends and get along" site. If you don't understand that, that's part of the problem. You need to go to the [about] page and the Coding Horror pages and the SE blog posts that detail the overall goals and intent of these sites, which is to **create a certain type of website** - sites that contain collections of knowledge. It isn't (and has never been) about solving the problems of a single individual.

Comment: @KenWhite But it *is* about people, since people are answering questions, and people are the ones who need answers. The purpose of SO is to create a resource that *people* can use. Stack Exchange needs a community to function--that's why we have chat, an aspect that otherwise doesn't help the site with its stated goals. Fortunately, I've discovered what jerkiness I've encountered in the past is atypical. People did actually answer the guy's question, after all, showing compassion. But the number of bad questions is still high, and we need to deal with it without becoming jerks--aka unfriendly.

Comment: @trikly: You're correct; it is a *resource*. It's not a chat room, discussion group, hold the newb's hand while they stumble around, tutorial, link collection site, or collection of useless clutter. As I said in my first comment, there are dozens of those sorts of site out there that are not part of SE. We don't need a new SE site to join that collection. The people answering questions are doing so to share knowledge (and some just for the rep), and if it happens to solve someone's immediate issue at the same time that's great.

Comment: @trlkly So you can imagine how telling the people answering questions that they absolutely must take the time to answer really crappy questions, that they have no way of ever getting rid of them, and that those users are more important, would be harmful to the well being of the site.  That is the attitude that most of this site's competitors took, in which people asking questions were the most important users.  Then SO came around and the people answering were the most important, and the askers had to go out of their way to treat *them*.  Unsurprisingly, those experts flocked to SO in droves.

Comment: @Servy I have made no such claim. Stop putting words into my mouth. You keep addressing things I haven't said, and it's getting rather annoying. I specifically commented on someone saying that this site is not "about people." I said nothing about the idea of opening another site (which would only work if it wasn't a Q&A site) nor about people being required to give answers. I did point out that some people do give answers as evidence of them being nice, but that doesn't mean that's the only way to be nice.

Comment: @Servy I know all about the history of this site. But I also know it's been mythologized into something it isn't. I've been finding answers online since the late 1990s. It wasn't nearly as bad as all that. The main problem was that there was a lot of cruft, but you usually could find an answer or find a place to ask it and get an answer. The same "experts" were still out there and still wanted to help. What Stack Exchange did was consolidate them and help remove the cruft. It still is not a great place to actually look for answers--You still use a search engine first.

Comment: @Servy. re:experts. None came in droves, because this site does not have subject matter experts. The system specifically encourages quick answers to the most common questions as the way to get the most reputation. It encourages users to stay on all day, responding to as much as possible, something a true expert doesn't have time for. The system actually continues to give points to people who have quit the site entirely and rewards people who dog other people about not picking their answers (the reason I left originally.) It's a good site, but it's not the magic place some people seem to think.